# Display a text file onto a text block which is already within the app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a text file in an app. Can someone please explain, algorithmically, how would I display the contents of the file on a text block.

`PS: I would be obliged if you didn't downvote this question as I'm banned from questioning further and trying to rectify my mistakes. Thank you, good sir.`

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: if you would like an exact answer, provide us with an exact question, i.e. more detail, what were you trying, code snippet....

Comment: Do you need to display a text from a file resource packed with the application? If so, check out Resources.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski is correct.  The implementation is trivial.  Try it, you'll like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code loaded file from your project directory and show it in `TextBlock` with a name `textBlock`

```
var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("file.txt", UriKind.Relative));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream);
textBlock.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Where file.txt saved like Content in your project

Comment: Application Resources is the way to do this now.  `GetResourceStream` is completely unnecessary.